# Javascript splice() based on value of ajacent element(s)

Tags: javascript, arrays

In pure JavaScript, using the getDaysArray function found elsewhere on Stack which produces a 1D array of Date objects, I am then inserting an element before every Sunday. If the next 6 days are a 1, then I insert the Month name, otherwise a spacer. Here is the working code:

```
const mon = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];

var getDaysArray = function(s,e) {for(var a=[],d=s;d<=e;d.setDate(d.getDate()+1)){ a.push(new Date(d));}return a;};
da = getDaysArray(new Date(2019,02,31), new Date(2019,04,04));

for(let elementIndex=0; elementIndex < da.length; elementIndex++){
    let q="";
    if(da[elementIndex].getDay() == 0) {
        for(let lookAheadIndex = elementIndex+1; lookAheadIndex<elementIndex+7; lookAheadIndex++){
            if (da[lookAheadIndex].getDate() == 1){
                q = mon[da[lookAheadIndex].getMonth()];
            }
        }
            q = (q != "") ? da.splice(elementIndex,0,q) : da.splice(elementIndex,0,'SPACER AT '+elementIndex);
    }
elementIndex++;
}
document.write(da + "<p>");
document.write(da.length);
```

Is there a better, faster, more elegant, cleaner way to accomplish this using built-in array methods? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Array.prototype() docs from MSDN have helped me out a lot in situations similar to yours. You may want to look into the methods available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of)

Comment: Thanks. I'd really like to replace the for loops with array.forEach but I'm having trouble with the forEach index after a splice insert. I understand that forEach determines the array length before the function, but even adding to the index within the function does not seem to work.